# How to iterate over divs of similar structure and extract by XPath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using WebDriver's *find_element**s**_by* methods to *collectively* grab the website, business name, phone and address of each of the 20 results in a page like [this](https://www.google.com/ncr#q=chiropractors%2BNew+York,+NY&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl)

So with:

```
# Business name
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_pl _ki']")

# Phone
phonesXpath = '//span[@class ="_FSf"]'
d=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(phonesXpath)

# Website
websitesXpath = '//a[@class ="rllt__action-button _Jrh"]'
d=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(websitesXpath)

# Review Counts
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_rl']/following-sibling::span[1]")]

etc.
```

I end up with a list of addresses, another list of phone numbers, and so on.

While I can then use `zip()` to reconstruct phone, address etc, for **each** of the 20 results, how can I achieve this directly? In other words, using knowledge of the page structure around each of the 20 result divs, how can I use the singular `find_element_by_xpath()` to iterate over each and grab the same information, individually?

Comment: What I would suggest that you do is to grab the outermost element that contains a single result and loop through those containers. For each container, pull the name, phone, reviews, etc. and associate them with that result. You can store that info in a class... that way as you scrape the page, you are able to keep the pieces for a single result together so you don't have to do it later when you can't tell what goes with what.

Comment: css selector "div.rl_full-list > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div" would give each row of container as WebElement, however, even if you're using your method to get separate list of 'name', 'address' div, you can use the same index of these list to retrieve single result. so where is the problem?

Comment: @JeffC. Thanks. I'm curious, is there a particular reason you suggest storing each set of result info in a class, rather than another data structure (dict, list, tuple etc.)?

Comment: I find class easiest to work with and the most flexible for handling multiple data types that you will likely need for scraping pages like this. It can handle strings, numerical types if needed, and you can also stick WebElements and Lists of WebElements in it. If you don't need that much data or that much flexibility then by all means use whatever data type fits your scenario. I typically have multiple bits of data that I want to keep together so I tend to use classes a lot.